# Imagick format conversion

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, imagick

I am trying to create thumbnails from pdf uploads using Imagick. I wrote a script that's supposed to do it, but, it only uploads the file without creating a thumbnail.
This will certainly make some of you roll your eyes, but, PHP is completely uncharted territory to me. Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
<?php
    include 'includes/session.php';
    include 'includes/slugify.php';

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $slug = slugify($name);
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $allowed = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'odc', 'jpg');


        $conn = $pdo->open();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM products WHERE slug=:slug");
        $stmt->execute(['slug'=>$slug]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if($row['numrows'] > 0){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'document already exists';
        }
        else{
            if(!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Filetype not allowed';
        }
         
        else{
            if(!empty($filename)){
                $new_filename = $slug.'.'.$ext;
                copy($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../documents/'.$new_filename);
                    
            }
            else{
                $new_filename = '';
```

**creating a thumbnail**

```
               $img = new Imagick($filename[0]); 
               $img-> setImageFormat('jpg');
               $convert = $slug. '.' .$jpg;
               $img-> writeImages($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$convert);

            }




            try{
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO products (category_id, name, description, 
            slug, price, photo) VALUES (:category, :name, :description, :slug, :price, : 
               photo)");
                $stmt->execute(['category'=>$category, 'name'=>$name, 
           'description'=>$description, 
               'slug'=>$slug, 'price'=>$price, 'photo'=>$new_filename]);
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'document added successfully';
             
             
            
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
}
        $pdo->close();
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up product form first';
    }

    header('location: documents.php');

?>
```

Comment: _"it doesn't do anything at all"_ - unlikely. More likely is that it's writing error messages to the server error log, so look there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your call to `$img->writeImages($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$convert)` is incorrect: you're passing two strings (the filename of an uploaded image and what looks like a destination filename) but the [Imagick documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimages.php) indicates you should be passing only a destination filename (along with an optional Boolean).

So this:

```
$img-> writeImages($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$convert);
```

Should probably be:

```
$img-> writeImages('../images/'.$convert);
```

Also, it's hard to tell whether the two chunks of PHP that you posted come one after the other, but if they do, then your logic for when to create the images looks faulty:

```
if(!empty($filename)){
    // Do some stuff
} else {
    // Write the images
}
```

The problem here is that the block of code that writes the images only executes when `$filename` is empty. Shouldn't it write the images if `$filename` is *not* empty?

Last but not least, the Imagick `writeImages()` function returns a Boolean indicating whether it was successful. You should store this result and log it to see what the result is. You should also confirm that your destination filename (`'../images/'.$convert`) is correct, and that the path exists and is writable.